# Direct sql query in magento not working

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am facing strange problem, when I use direct SQL query method in Magento controller its not working

```
    $resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $connection   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
    $table        = $resource->getTableName('toynav_referral');

    $query        = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`referral_id`,`email`,`coupon`) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
    $connection->query($query);
```

But when I use this in controller its working fine and one thing the fetch method works everywhere as expected.
When I debug in the system.log file i got the below error

> User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back  in /var/www/vhosts/************/httpdocs/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3937

Please advise me

Comment: where do you want to use this? in a save operation maybe? if you use this while a mysql-transaction is happening, this may be a problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to begin transaction and then commit it.

```
$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table        = $resource->getTableName('toynav_referral');

try
{
    $connection->beginTransaction();

    $query        = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`referral_id`,`email`,`coupon`) VALUES ('1', '2', '3')";
    $connection->query($query);

    $connection->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $connection->rollBack();
}
```

Comment: Still same result

Comment: I am not sure whats blocking me from committing.

Comment: Please add exception logging
`...}catch (Exception $e){
    $connection->rollBack();
    Mage::logException($e);
}`

Comment: Or try to use the Zend_Db 'insert' statement
`try
{
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    $data = array(
        'referral_id' => $id,
        'email' => $email,
        'coupon' => $couponCode,
    );
    $connection->insert($table, $data);
}catch (Exception $e){
    $connection->rollBack();
    Mage::logException($e);
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try to Make an log  like below...

```
Mage::log(var_export($query, TRUE), null,'query.log');
Mage::log(var_export($connection,TRUE),null,'connection.log');
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with your block of code.

I believe this error is happening because this perticular block is being run in the midst of a higher level transaction.

The solution to you problem is putting this block of code either before the beginning of the transaction or after the transaction is being commited.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Please check with this

```
$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection   = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$table        = $resource->getTableName('toynav_referral');
$query        = "INSERT INTO ". $table ."(referral_id,email,coupon) VALUES ('1','2','3')";
$connection->query($query);
```

I hope it will help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the following flow to debug the transaction, maybe it will be helpful.

```
$resource     = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$connection   = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
$table        = $resource->getTableName('toynav_referral');

try
{
    $connection->beginTransaction();
    $query        = "INSERT INTO ". $table ."(referral_id,email,coupon) VALUES ('1','2','3')";
    $connection->query($query);
    $connection->commit();
}
catch (Exception $e)
{
    $connection->rollBack();
    Mage::logException($e);
}
```

You can trace it in the log if any error in the commit.